# Llenar Select en Html desde la database de Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Quiero saber si existe una forma adecuada de código para realizar el llenado de un select en html desde la database de Firebase, es decir, obtener los valores que tengo registrados en firebase y mostrarlos en el select de html...

Este es el select que quiero llenar:

```
<select id="tipoatencion" onchange="ShowSelected();" class="seleccion" name="tipoatencion">
    <option value="Seleccion">Selecciona un tipo de atención</option>
    <option value="pu">Público</option>
    <option value="ca">Caja</option>
    <option value="otros">Otros servicios</option>
</select>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias a todos!

Comment: cual versión en Firebase esta usando?

Comment: Muchas gracias por la consulta @JacksonQuintero pero ya solucioné el problema. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hice desde un archivo JS de la siguiente manera:

```
 var db = firebase.firestore(); //Mando a llamar la instancia de base de datos

    var selected_item = document.getElementById('select_empresa');//Se llama el selected
    selected_item.innerHTML = '';
    selected_item.innerHTML += `
            <option value="0" selected>Selecciona la empresa a la que perteneces</option>
            ` //Agrego un option por default
    db.collection("company").onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => { //Se llaman los datos
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data().name}`);
            selected_item.innerHTML += `
            <option value="${doc.id}">${doc.data().name}</option> . 
            ` //Aquí agrego los options de acuerdo a la base de datos.
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Sí. Puedes hacerlo pero no directamente.

Tienes que hacer un servicio WEB (sobre HTTP) que devuelva esos valores extraídos del a tabla de Firebase, para que puedas utilizarlo dentro de JavaScript (o renderearlos directamente en tu HTML).

Comment: Puede ser una solución, nunca he hecho o utilizado un web service, pero podría funcionar. Muchas gracias...